# while loop printing blank <option></option>

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I have a function that generates the content for drop down `<select>` `<option>`s

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option name="the-correct-display">The Correct Display</option>
    <option></option>
    <option name="the-correct-display">The Correct Display</option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the blanks? Here's the function:

```
function catalogGetColors($mysqli)
{
    $query = 'SELECT sectionName FROM sections';
    if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
            $optName = strstr(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $row['pName'])), '-', true);
            printf('<option name="%s">%s<option>', $optName, $row['pName']);
        }
    } else {
        printf('Something went wrong.');
    }
}
```

This is a prototype build to be used internally so I'm not worried about prepared statements or PDO (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

> By using the MYSQLI_ASSOC constant this function will behave identically to the mysqli_fetch_assoc(), while MYSQLI_NUM will behave identically to the mysqli_fetch_row() function. The final option MYSQLI_BOTH will create a single array with the attributes of both.

Essentially by using `MYSQLI_BOTH` your output results will be returned in an associative format **and** with numeric indexes, causing duplicate results which is probably why you've got empty values.

You should use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` here instead:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
```